# Regex to match a unicode character except when used at the end of a word

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, sed, grep

I need to find and replace all occurrences (except for at the end of a word) of a certain character in a bunch of RTL text. I am having trouble finding or understanding a regex solution that works.

I have tried `(?<=\w)ی(?=\w)`, `ی(?=\w)`, and `(?<=\w)ی`, but can't get anything to match. Other solutions using `\b` or `\w` seem to return more than just the `ی‍` character.

for example, I would like to find and replace the 'ی' in the following words,

```
گیر
غیبت
قیمت
یرغال
```

but *not* in these words,

```
کسی
کمی
```

Can anyone provide a solution that I could use with `sed` in bash, or JavaScript?

*Note:* these words are occurring in a big stream of text, not as individual strings or lines.

**Edit:** Here is another example, using English words. (Hopefully the solution will work the same with RTL or LTR text).

I would like to find and replace 'x' in these words:

`axe xylophone exec`

But *not*,

`borax, anthrax`

Thanks!

Comment: I think using just english words would help us assist you easier.

Comment: Maybe you could check for a non-whitespace character following `ی`.

Comment: @BogdanM. the problem is related to RTL text, english won't really cause the same problems

Comment: Since you tagged with JS, check this [`\u06cc(?=[\u0600-\u06ff])`](https://regex101.com/r/6Taqj6/1)

Comment: thank you @revo that works great with JS!

Comment: Are your "words" always one per line or space-separated as shown in your example?

Comment: @Ed Morton, like I mentioned, it's just a bunch of words space-separated. (A big file of prose text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` supports POSIX flavor which compared to modern regex flavors has limited features. Below workaround uses JS but for sure would be portable for `sed` (some bash / `sed` guru may do it):

```
\u06cc(?=[\u0600-\u06ff])
```

Matches a `ی` letter that is followed by another letter in Arabic block (`0600`-`06ff`)

```js
var str = `گیر
غیبت
قیمت
یرغال
کسی
کمی
`;

str.split(/\n/).forEach(function(word){
  if (/\u06cc(?=[\u0600-\u06ff])/.test(word)) {
    console.log(word);
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm just looking to replace certain letters, not list all the words that contain a certain letter. So with @revo 's suggestion I can just do  str.replace(/\u06cc(?=[\u0200-\u06ff])/g, 'ي') and it works great.

Comment: This is revo's  answer. I did it since there wouldn't be a simple way to highlight `ی` here. It just shows words that a match within them is found.

Comment: Oops, sorry I misunderstood that. Thanks for this super helpful answer. Wondering if there's some sed/bash guru that could port that to sed/bash...

Comment: You're welcome. As I'm not sure about `sed` you could use `perl` with `-C` flag like this: `perl -pCSD -i.bak -e 's/\x{06cc}(?=[\x{0600}-\x{06ff}])//g' file`

Comment: Ah, so I didn't understand what you meant because my English isn't good enough. OK, got it, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @EdMorton No, that just happens sometimes. It's better not to get deep into it. It may go nowhere.

Comment: @revo Your perl solution works perfectly, thank you! In my use case... `perl -pCSD -i.bak -e 's/\x{06cc}(?=[\x{0600}-\x{06ff}])/\x{064a}/g' text-file.txt` Big props to @revo's understanding of unicode text and regex!!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this all you need?

```
$ sed 's/x\([^[:space:]]\)/Y\1/g' file
aYe Yylophone eYec
borax anthrax
```

or depending on what defines and/or separates your "words" maybe one of these:

```
$ sed 's/x\([[:alpha:]]\)/Y\1/g' file
aYe Yylophone eYec
borax anthrax

$ sed 's/x\([^[:punct:][:space:]]\)/Y\1/g' file
aYe Yylophone eYec
borax anthrax
```

or whatever other other combination of character classes define either your concept of a word-constituent character or a word-separator. Also with GNU sed for `\w` meaning `word-constituent character`:

```
$ sed 's/x\(\w\)/Y\1/g' file
aYe Yylophone eYec
borax anthrax
```

Comment: How can OP be sure that `ی` letter is in middle of a word? Is `\w` in gnu sed unicode aware?

Comment: We'll know once the OP tests it and/or looks up the man page.

Comment: @EdMorton Ya, I can't get it to work by typing in the unicode ی character with this unfortunately.

Comment: OK, it was worth a shot. I don't know anything about unicode other than I see the word thrown around but are you sure you're using a sed (or, possibly more importantly, locale such as en_US.UTF-8) that supports unicode characters? If its not already set, try setting `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` before you execute the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

For your LTR example you can use `x\B` - a literal `x` and then "not a word boundary" marker.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, using \B
If you want all characters except when it appears in the end of a word you use \B\B, example: this will match all characters "e", except when this is the last character:

t**e**st

found**e**r

s**e**e

if you want to replace this same character in all words, except the words that ends with this character, you can use: .*[^e]$ to get all these words, and then apply a new regex to find all "e" words. Example:

Step 1: .*[^e]$

**test**

**founder**

see

---

Step 2: e

t**e**st

found**e**r

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @revo's suggestion I now have a good JavaScript solution:

`str.replace(/\u06cc(?=[\u0200-\u06ff])/g, '\u064A')`

where `\u06cc` is the character I want to replace (except when it occurs at the end of the word) and `\u064A` is the character I'm replacing it with.

**edit:** [Revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) also gave a great solution which uses perl. Not sed, but does exactly what I wanted it to do. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) is a super helpful legend. Thanks!!

`perl -pCSD -i.bak -e 's/\x{06cc}(?=[\x{0600}-\x{06ff}])/\x{064a}/g' text-file.txt`

`06cc` is the unicode character to be replaced. `064a` is what it's replacing it with.